# Can't login to Gmail or MSN. Server says cookies are turned off, but they're not

Tags: google-chrome, browser, gmail, login, cookies

I have a PC with Windows 7 installed and I'm using both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox for browsing the Internet. Recently I encountered a problem where I am not able to log in to Gmail or MSN. The Gmail server says my browser cookies are turned off but they're not.

The strange thing is I visited http://mail.google.com using 3 different browsers (Chrome, Firefox and IE) and yet I get the same error in all of them. I am able to log in to some websites (Facebook) but not others (MSN). What could be the problem?

Comment: I tried resetting Firefox to factory default state but I still face the same problem

Comment: This sounds like a network filtering problem.

Comment: Check your antivirus/firewall and/or router. Something is most likely blocking them,.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your system clock and date is set correctly. If these are off many processes that rely on time stamps cease to function.

Answer (score -1):

try to clear Temporary file :
RUN> temp

RUN> %temp%

RUN> Recent

RUN> prefetch

And to delete all the browsing DATA , History and Cookies .

Delete all the file that can be deleted .

If problem remains still just do one thing Uninstall the browser and clear Registry  Settings for the Browser Also look for the program file of the browser and delete them too